# $f^{-1}f(\Sigma)$ has measure zero for analytic map from manifolds $M$ to $N$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Differential Topology Hirsch Chapter 3 Section 1 Problem 4: (a) Let $M$ be a connected manifold and $f: M \rightarrow N$ an analytic map. Let $\Sigma \subset M$ be the set of critical points. If $\Sigma \neq M$ then $f^{-1}f(\Sigma)$ has measure zero.

(b) If $f$ is merely $C^{\infty}$ The conclusion (a) can be false.

For part (a) A function is analytic iff its Taylor series about $x_0$ converges to the function in some neighborhood for every $x_0$ in the domain. The definition of analytic function is the same as $C^{\infty}$ function except for the notion of convergence in a neighborhood of nonzero radius in the former. Therefore, we can apply the Morse-Sard Theorem and conclude that the set of regular values is dense. A critical point cannot be a regular value so $f^{-1}f(\Sigma)$, which is the set of critical points must have measure 0.

For part (b) I didn't use anything about the function being analytic in part (a) so I'm not sure how I would approach this part.

Thank you!

Comment: It works a lot better when the title describes the question, and not cites the origin of the question (this should be mentioned in the body of the question, though). This extends to your other questions, of course.

Comment: I see. I'll change all of them when I find the time. Thank you for this tip

Comment: @Math_Day I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to do this question myself, and I have not been able to do it yet . Now for the counterexample part of a smooth function $f: M\rightarrow N$ such that $f^{-1}(f(\Sigma))$ doesn't have null measure, I think an idea would be to consider $M=N=\mathbb{R}$ and take a bump function. We would have that $\Sigma\neq \mathbb{R}$ since there are points where the derivative is non-zero and so the differential is surjective, and we would have that $f^{-1}(f(\Sigma))$ wouldn't have measure zero.  So I don't think your argument works, but I haven't been able to prove this myself. I am guessing it will use some local property of real analytic functions , but I am not very aware of these so I will try to look things up.

Here's the attempt at proving the statement , the idea is similar to what Hirsch did to prove the Morse-Sard theorem, and notice we can assume that $\dim M\geq \dim N$:

Notice that we can do this locally and assume we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ analytic.
Let $\Sigma_f$ denote the set of critical points of $f$.We will see that $m(\Sigma_f)=0$.  We have that $f_i(x_1,...,x_m)=\sum a^i_{k_1}...a{k_m}(z)(x_1-z_1)^{k_1}...(x_m-z_m)^{k_m}$. We can divide $\Sigma_f$ into two sets, let $\Sigma_1$ denote the set of points $x\in \Sigma$ such that $\nabla f_i(x)\neq 0$ for some differential operator of order $\geq 2$, and $\Sigma_2$ the set of $x\in \Sigma$ such that $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)\neq 0$ for some $i\in \{1,..,n\}$ and $j\in \{1,..,m\}$. We notice that $\Sigma\subset \Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$ since if we have that $\frac{\partial f _i}{\partial x_j}(z)=0$ and $\nabla f_i(z)=0$ for every $i,j$ and differential operator of order $\geq 2$ then we will have that $a^i_{k_1}...a_{k_m}(z)=0$ which would contradict the fact that $f\neq 0$ since $M$ is connected.

Now Let's see that $\Sigma_1- \Sigma_2$ has null measure. We can consider the set of points $x\in M$ such that $\nabla f(x)= 0$ and $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\neq 0$, and this set will form a submanifold of dimension $m-1$ which we will call $M_{\nabla },i,j$. We have that $\Sigma_1-\Sigma_2 \subset \cup_{\nabla,i,j}X_{\nabla,i,j}$ where this union is over a countable set , and since $M$ is a $n-1$\submanifold it will have null measure so that $\Sigma_1-\Sigma_2$ has null measure.

If $x\in \Sigma_2$ we will have that there exists $f_i$ such that $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)\neq 0$ and so there exists an open set $U$ such that $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)\neq 0$ for $x\in U$.Now using the Implicit function theorem for analytic functions we have that there exists a function $h:A\times B\rightarrow U$ such that $f_i(h(x,t))=t$, for $(x,t)\in A\times B$. And so $f(h(x,t))=(u_t(x),t)$ and so being a critical point of $f$ is equivalent to being a critical point for $u_t:A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, and so by induction hypothesis we have that $m(\Sigma_{u_t})=0$ and then using the fubini theorem we get that $m(\Sigma_f\cap U)=0$. Since we can cover $\Sigma_f$ by a coutable number of these open sets we get the desired result.

Now we already know that $\Sigma_f\subset f^{-1}(f(\Sigma))$ has zero measure , we just need to see that $f^{-1}(f(\Sigma))-\Sigma_f$ also has null measure. Let $x\in f^{-1}(f(\Sigma_f))-\Sigma_f$ then we will have that $d_x f$ is surjective. And so there will exist an open set $x\in U=A\times B\subset M$ and parametrizations such that $\bar f=\psi^\circ f\circ \phi^{-1} : U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ looks like the canonical projection. Since $K:=\hat f(\phi(\Sigma_f))\subset A$ has null measure by Sard's theorem, we will have that $\hat f^{-1}(K)=K\times B$ will have null measure by Fubini's theorem, and so $m(\hat f^{-1}(f(\Sigma_f)))=0$. Now since $\phi^{-1}$ takes null measure sets into null measure sets we have that $m(\phi^{-1}(\hat f^{-1}(f(\Sigma_f))))=m( f^{-1}(f(\Sigma))\cap U)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up! I have a question regarding the case when $x \in \Sigma_2$: could you expand a bit on what is the induction hypothesis and how we get that $m(\Sigma_{u_t}) = 0$? Thanks!